# could not import Text.Reges.Posix in a haskell script

Tags: haskell, package

i have a strange problem, when I'm in **ghci** and type:

`:module Text.Reges.Posix`

the module will be loaded and i can use it, but when i write a script (and try to load or compile it) with

```
import Text.Reges.Posix
```

i get the massage:

```
could not find module: Text.Reges.Posix
```

what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `Text.Regex.Posix` -- you're spelling it wrong.

Comment: OMG -.- what a stupid bug, thanks

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?